# Elasticsearch sort on formula with values from nested aggregations

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, aggregation

I would like to sort on a formula that takes value from nested aggregation and compute it with parent aggregation document count.

I want to sort by this formula result:

> national_averages_9_10.avg * national_averages_9_10.count / key.doc_count
>
> where key.doc_count = root bucket document count

More specifically, for first result document, the formula is:

> 9.543799991607665 * 100 / 194 = 4.919484

I have the following search:

```
GET student-grade/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "schools": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "SCHOOL_NAME.keyword",
        "size": 2,
        "shard_size": 250,
        "min_doc_count": 20
      },
      "aggs": {
        "national_averages_9_10": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "STUDENT_NATIONAL_AVERAGE_GRADE": {
                "gte": 9,
                "lte": 10
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "range_stats": {
              "stats": {
                "field": "STUDENT_NATIONAL_AVERAGE_GRADE"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This produce this sample output:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "schools": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 10790,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Școala Gimnazială nr. 195",
          "doc_count": 194,
          "national_averages_9_10": {
            "doc_count": 100,
            "range_stats": {
              "count": 100,
              "min": 9.020000457763672,
              "max": 10,
              "avg": 9.543799991607665,
              "sum": 954.3799991607666
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "Școala Gimnazială nr. 56",
          "doc_count": 178,
          "national_averages_9_10": {
            "doc_count": 110,
            "range_stats": {
              "count": 110,
              "min": 9,
              "max": 10,
              "avg": 9.566909139806574,
              "sum": 1052.3600053787231
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "schools": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "SCHOOL_NAME.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "national_averages_9_10": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "STUDENT_NATIONAL_AVERAGE_GRADE": {
                "gte": 9,
                "lte": 10
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "range_stats": {
              "stats": {
                "field": "STUDENT_NATIONAL_AVERAGE_GRADE"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "my_formula": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "school_total_count": "_count",
              "average_9_10_total_count": "national_averages_9_10._count",
              "average": "national_averages_9_10>range_stats.avg"
            },
            "script": "params.average * params.average_9_10_total_count / params.school_total_count"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your solution is not complete. it calculates the value for formula I'm interested. The missing part is sorting by this value. Basically, I want to order by "my_formula.value".

Comment: You cannot use the value of `my_formula` to order the buckets in `schools` aggregation because that's a pipeline aggregation. And that's a limitation when it comes to sorting a `terms` aggregation buckets: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order

Comment: And I don't know if you can do it without a bucket_script aggregation.

Comment: I know the sorting on bucket_script is not supported. Is any solution to my problem, other than bucket_script?

Comment: I don't think so, in my opinion.

Comment: I was afraid of your "not supported" answer. In this case I can't consider your answer as the response to my question because of sorting. I would consider a not possible answer.